# C++ pointer to char

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

namespace std;

void main(){
    char *ch;
    char nch;
    cout<<"\n"<<sizeof(ch);
    cout<<\n"<<sizeof(nch);
    cout<<"\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

This program would print the output as:

```
8
1
```

Why does the size of char type change when it is a pointer?

Comment: Because `sizeof(ch)` returns the size of the pointer, which in your case is 8 bytes. `sizeof(*ch)` You need to de ref the pointer in order to get the size of the object it points to.

Comment: Why would you expect `sizeof char` to be related to `sizeof char*`?

Comment: Because pointers are not characters ... its that easy.

Comment: All pointers are from the same size - to `char` or to big structure.

Comment: .... no. Pointers can vary in size, sometimes (though rarely) even on the same machine under different circumstances - thats why `size_t ptrSize = sizeof(ptr)` is preferred over a constant value ... magic numbers are generally bad.

Comment: @i486:  That is ***not true*** Pointers can be different sizes.  You get two guarantees:  1.  void* and [unsigned|signed|] char* are big enough to hold any object pointer (you can cast a pointer to any object to void* and back, and you will obtain the same pointer).  2.  Pointers to any struct and class are compatible.  (Cast a pointer to any struct to a pointer to any other struct *and back* and you will obtain the same value).  The Prime minicomputer in particular had sizeof(int*)==4, and sizeof(char*)==6.

Comment: In addition, if you are prepared to rely on Posix, you are guaranteed that a pointer to function can be cast into a void* and back without loss.  (Although that guarantee may not be *iron-cast*.  It may only apply to functions in libraries which are dlloaded.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Are you sure that The Prime minicomputer has C++ compiler or only C? Because the question is for C++ and we assume to talk about today's PCs, not for abstract computer from any age. Theoretically you are right, but in practice it is too rare to find system which has different size of pointers. At least the programmer who works there will not ask here :)

Comment: @i486.  There was only a C compiler for Prime. I prefer to talk about what is guaranteed by the standard, not what is a common architecture today.

Comment: I quoted the Prime to point out that the liberties that compilers are allowed to take, actually have been used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointer to char is not a char, it is a pointer. Size of a pointer does not depend on the size of the object it points to. Because pointer is basically an address of the first byte of the object.

Comment: Actually the size of a pointer *may* depend on the size of the object it points to.  As I said on the question:  The Prime minicomputer had sizeof(int*)==4, and sizeof(char*)==6.  (The Prime was a 16-bit word addressed machine.  An int* was simply two words: segment + offset; a char* had to be *three* words:  segment+offset+bit_offset_within_word.  The segment word had a bit in it which indicated whether the bit offset word was present.)

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are not the data they're pointing to and `char *` is not the same type as `char`.

Most pointers have the same size and it's generally machine architecture dependent, in your case it happend to be 8 bytes, so you pretty much can expect something among the lines:

```
int* pInt;
char* pChar;
std::cout << (sizeof(pInt) == sizeof(pChar)); // prints 1 for true
```

On the other hand `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to return `1`. But this still doesn't guarantee the ammount of actual memory used to store it, funny enough.

If you want to get the size of actual data pointed to by the pointer you, of course, can dereference it:

```
std::cout << sizeof(*ch); // prints 8
```

Comment: Thank you, Is it right to say by default pointer has the size == integer

Comment: @Romi Not always, but you can expect it to be in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof *ch
```

The catch is that `ch` is a `pointer to char`, so `ch` is **not** a `char`. It just stores an address. For storing an address, it needs some space and in many systems, that happen to be **8 bytes**

```
sizeof(nch)
```

prints the size of `char` type in a system and it is **1 byte**.

Comment: `sizeof(nch)` doesn't **print** anything. Its value is 1.

Comment: @PeteBecker return value*

Comment: @PeteBecker : Is there any confusion in those lines, i just wanted to highlight those lines.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't, but the size of a pointer may be different than the size of a character. If you change your code from `sizeof(ch)` to `sizeof(*ch)`, then you'll get `1 1`.